# Replacing the contents of a vector with another R

Tags: r, string, vector, replace

How would I be able to make a new vector `vectB` where it replaces the contents of `vectA` (`'ab','cd','bc'`) with `'aa','bb','cc'`. So the output of `vectB` would be `'aa','bb','aa','cc'`. The contents of `vectA` would be unchanged.

```
vectA <- c('ab','cd','ab','bc')
```

Comment: Please don't call vectors lists. This is a `character` vector, not a `list()`.

Comment: my bad meant to say vector i will edit it

Comment: How do you want to do this replacement: just a straight hard-coded "replace this with that", or (I only ask since you put the regex tag on it) is it something more like "change every 2-letter string by deleting the second letter and repeating the first letter"?

Comment: And, are there other values in the vector that remain unchanged, or are all the values included in the replacing?

Comment: And I assume your output has a typo, the last entry should have `'bc'` changed to `'cc'`?

Comment: yes sorry about that edited the question once again,. I want to create a new `vectB` based on the contents of `vectA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common approach is to use a named vector, where the values are the desired values, and the names are the old values.

```
lookup = c("ab" = 'aa', 'cd' = 'bb', 'bc' = 'cc')

vectB = unname(lookup[match(vectA, names(lookup))])
vectB
[1] "aa" "bb" "aa" "cc"
```

Another common approach is to use `factor` labels. (You can of course use `as.character` after if you don't want a `factor` class result.)

```
B = factor(vectA, levels = c("ab", "cd", "bc"), labels = c("aa", "bb", "cc"))
B
# [1] aa bb aa cc
# Levels: aa bb cc
```

These both assume that all values in A will be present in the recoding lookup.